# hide password protected posts from wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I found this in the codex:

```
// Filter to hide protected posts
function exclude_protected($where) {
    global $wpdb;
    return $where .= " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_password = '' ";
}

// Decide where to display them
function exclude_protected_action($query) {
    if( !is_single() && !is_page() && !is_admin() ) {
        add_filter( 'posts_where', 'exclude_protected' );
    }
}

// Action to queue the filter at the right time
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_protected_action');
```

But it didn't work. Perhaps because I've customised my loop. I was hoping to do something simple, along these lines:

```
<?php $postsLatest = get_posts('numberposts=10&passwordproteced=false'); foreach($postsLatest as $post) { ?>
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Did you try the `has_password` parameter?

Comment: yes, to no avail unfortunately...

Comment: aha, this will work on WordPress 3.9+ so test again after upgrading ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this inside your custom loop.

```
<?php
    if ( post_password_required() ) {
            continue;
    } else {
           echo 'normal post';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

### The `has_password` and `post_password` parameters in WordPress 3.9+

You wrote:

> I was hoping to do something simple, along these lines:
>
> ```
> passwordproteced=false
> ```

You're pretty close, because you can use the boolean `has_password` parameter:

```
$postsLatest = get_posts( 'has_password=false' );
```

to fetch posts without passwords.

You can read more about this parameter in the [Codex for  `WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Password_Parameters), since `get_posts` just a wrapper for `WP_Query()`, and shares the input parameters.

**Notice** that this will only work on WordPress `3.9+`:

> has_password (bool) - true for posts with passwords ; false for posts
>   without passwords ; null for all posts with and without passwords
>   (available with Version 3.9).

There's also another new `post_password` parameter with possible values:

- null (ignore)
- false (only posts without passwords)
- true (only posts with passwords)
- a string (posts with this exact password)

You can check this [Trac Ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20308).

### Using `pre_get_posts` filter with get_posts:

The reason why you didn't succeed with the `pre_get_posts` filter, is that `get_posts()` suppresses all `pre_get_posts` filters by default. Use the `suppress_filters=false` parameter to apply it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried the has_password parameter, but it didn't work unfortunately. Would have been a nice solution...

Comment: The `has_password` parameter works only on WordPress `3.9+`, so please try it again after upgrading ;-)

Comment: oh awesome, I'll give it a go. It's not out yet is it?

Comment: it's just around the corner ;-) The target date for release of WordPress 3.9 is 16th of April 2014.